# How does one add a collaborator in Github using the command line?

Tags: github, terminal, github-api

I'd like to know how to add a collaborator to a private repo in GitHub using the command line.  I'm on a mac (10.6.8) or Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither [github gem](https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem) nor  [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub) (these are two popular command line interfaces for github) provide functionality to add a collaborator to a repo. This means that the only way to add a collaborator from the command line is to use curl and accessing the github api directly  (the [github api](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-collaborator) allows for collaborator addition/removal/listing).

Here is how for example I added a collaborator to my own repo, together with github's response   when I did that (the response isn't very helpful - but it is what you get on success):

```
> curl -i -u "my_user_name:my_password" -X PUT -d '' 'https://api.github.com/repos/my_gh_userid/my_repo/collaborators/my_collaborator_id'

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 06:45:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 204 No Content
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.beta
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control:
```

The relevant add collaborator API page is [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-collaborator)  and [this](https://gist.github.com/2288960) is the page that explains how to use curl to use the github API from the command line in general.
Hope this helps.

FYI, I found your answer when I was looking to do exactly what you were asking - and couldn't find a satisfactory answer (besides using curl...).  I plan to ask the maintainer of "hub" to see why he has not add that functionality to his tool.

Comment: I used this method to add several exiting GitHub accounts to several private repos of mine, and was surprised to see that the accounts were added directly, by-passing the invitation process. The new collaborators only received emails stating that they were now following additional repos.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a token for them - take a look at https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use.

It's usually a lot easier to do it through the web interface though.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/collaborators?apiVersion=2022-11-28#add-collaborator) you can use the Github CLI to add Colleborators.

```
gh api \
  --method PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/collaborators/USERNAME \
  -f permission='triage'
```

Then you can build a script around this to add multiple collaborators in one go or to multiple repos. (The github web UI does not support this I believe)